# How to check for first/last row of an array in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I've built a basic navigation menu in which the sub menus are controlled by arrays, however (only for style purposes at the minute) I want to be able to check when the array is outputting the first/last line so that I can remove the bottom border on the `<li>` giving a neat and tidy sub menu. If anyone would be able to help, it would be greatly appreciated.

How to do it:

```
<cfset thisArray = [
    {name="Page", href="page.cfm"},
    {name="Page2", href="page2.cfm"}
]>
<cfif arrayLen(thisArray) neq 0>
    <cfset start = 1>
    <ul>
        <cfloop array="#thisArray#" index="array">
            <cfif start eq arrayLen(thisArray)>
                <li class="navItem" style="border-bottom: 0;"><a href="#array['href']#">#array['name']#</a></li>
            <cfelse>
                <li class="navItem"><a href="#array['href']#">#array['name']#</a></li>
            </cfif>
            <cfset start = start + 1>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
</cfif>
```

That is basically how I want it to work, check for the last row, or the current row matching last row, this usually works fine for queries however I can tell it doesn't for arrays as I haved tried this method and it didn't work for me. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I have literally just found a solution, using a custom variable called `start` and setting it to one, each time the loop is performed it increments by 1 and a check is performed against the arrays length, if `start` is equal to it, then it simply removes the bottom border now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This started as a comment but it got a little long winded.
Miguel-F's answer is good under most conditions but it does contain a possible flaw.

Consider:

```
<cfset myArray=["Z","Y","X","A","B","C"]> 
<cfset myArray[20]="gotcha!">
<cfoutput>
    #arrayLen(myArray)# <!--- 20 --->
</cfoutput>
```

The counter in Miguel-F's solution will only reach 7 because unlike `arrayLen` `cfloop` ignores the empty elements.

The solution to this little problem is to change

```
<cfset i = 0>
<cfloop array="#thisArray#" index="array">
    <cfset i = i + 1>
    <cfif i eq ArrayLen(thisArray)>
```

to

```
<cfset i = 0>
<cfset lastRow = listLen(arrayToList(thisArray,"^"),"^")> 
<!--- You can change your delim to your choice of obscure delims --->
<cfloop array="#thisArray#" index="array">
    <cfset i = i + 1>
    <cfif i eq lastRow>
```

For simple arrays or arrays containing complex data like yours, you can also do this; I used an index loop instead of looping the array directly:

```
<cfset thisArray = [
    {name="Page", href="page.cfm"},
    {name="Page2", href="page2.cfm"}
]>
<cfset thisArray[20]={name="Page20", href="page20.cfm"}>
<cfif arrayLen(thisArray) neq 0>
    <ul>
        <cfloop from = "1" to = "#arrayLen(thisArray)#" index="i">
            <cfif arrayIsDefined(thisArray,i)>
                <cfif i eq arrayLen(thisArray)>
                    <li class="navItem" style="border-bottom: 0;"><a href="#thisArray[i]['href']#">#thisArray[i]['name']#</a></li>
                <cfelse>
                    <li class="navItem"><a href="#thisArray[i]['href']#">#thisArray[i]['name']#</a></li>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
</cfif>
```

Comment: This issue will only arise if you are manually setting array values beyond the last (previous) index. Why would you do that? If you use the built-in array functions this can be avoided. Still, point taken. Your solution will also add some overhead in converting the array to a list in order to then get the list length for comparison.

Comment: It will add less overhead than calculating arrayLen each pass. ;)  There are several reasons why you may not use sequential indexes.  Perhaps your array indexes are the same as your recordIDs for example.

Comment: Could you expalin the `^` delimiter to me please? I'm not quite sure what it's purpose is :)

Comment: Yes, I moved the ArrayLen out of the loop.

Comment: Oh wait, is it the custom delimiter you used when putting the array into the list?

Comment: @LeeB - just be sure that the delimiter you select is not contained within the elements of your array.

Comment: right because if a value in your array has a `,` in it, your listLen value will be wrong.  You can use something super obscure like `chr(7)` instead of `^` as well.

Comment: Basically use any kind of character that will never at any point feature within the array. I'm with you now thanks for clearing it up :)

Comment: "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values. " this was the error i recieved when using the above code, not quite sure what went wrong?

Comment: You must have something goofy in there somewhere, I just tested it and it works great.

Comment: I've had a look through and I can't see from a first glance what the issue is. I've reverted to `<cfset lastrow = arrayLen(thisArray)>` as currently this provides no issues for me, however if I do run into any errors I will keep this post in mind and refer back to it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @LeeB ah yes, because you're using an array of structures, I tested with basic values.

Comment: @LeeB Miguel-F's answer will work for your current situation but if you end up with non-sequential indexes in the future, I updated my answer to solve your array of structures issue. It will work for CF8+, it requires the arrayIsDefined function.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a counter and check if it's value is equal to the number of elements in your array.  Something like this:

```
<cfset i = 0>
<cfset lengthOfArray = ArrayLen(thisArray)>
<ul>
<cfloop array="#thisArray#" index="array">
    <cfset i = i + 1>
    <cfif i eq lengthOfArray>
        <li class="navItem" style="border-bottom: 0;"><a href="#array['href']#">#array['name']#</a></li>
    <cfelse>
        <li class="navItem"><a href="#array['href']#">#array['name']#</a></li>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
</ul>
```

As Travis mentions in his answer, this solution will only work if you are using sequential indexes for your array as you are in your example.

Comment: Literally figured it out within moments of posting the question, however ill mark your answer correct and leave the question up as it may help others in the future.

Comment: @LeeB There is a potential error in this solution. please see my answer for details.